# Best way to customize my site when viewed through iframes?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe

I have a site where users need to access our material in two ways:

1. from the site itself
2. from iframes embedded into another site

My site handles #1 very nicely, and now I'm trying to extend its functionality to iframes that can be easily embedded. Essentially, I need to get rid of the site header, the site footer, and change some CSS for every page that is shown through an iframe (users need to be able to navigate quite a few pages using this iframe).

When trying the `<iframe>` tag, I get my site appearing but exactly as it normally does, showing its header bar, footer, etc. inside the iframe.

What's the best way to allow users to navigate my site while changing the layout and CSS?

Comment: You shouldn't really offer your entire side through an iframe, you should create an api or a widget.

Comment: @Babiker - it isn't really the entire site, it's just a sizable collection of pages. But point taken - if an api/widget is necessary is there a good source you know of to learn about creating one?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if the page is being viewed from an iframe via Javascript by adding this to the "domready" event (framework dependent):

```
var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
```

Wrap the affected areas in containers and `display=none;` the stuff you would like hidden when accessed via iframe.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic but it really annoys me when I see people do `x = someBoolean ? true : false`.  You can simplify that code to just 'var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location);`  Otherwise, this is a good suggestion.

Comment: This is probably indeed the easiest way to do it, but there are some site designs that won't work very well like this. A reasonable alternative would be to check the referrer address to see if a user is coming from the 3rd party site and then solve this issue server-side.

Comment: @Battle_707 Referrer could be plenty of things that don't indicate an iframe.  It's just the page the request originated from, could be a SERP, a link on some partner site.

Comment: @Endophage: yes, this is not the best solution by a long shot, even if it were for the fact that many people using FF have the referrer turned off. What I tried to indicate was that, when possible, you should want to take care of this server-side, as that should save you the trouble of sending data that will then be removed from view. Also, sadly, some people have JS turned off, so this solution could be seen as a fall-back. In the ideal situation, the 3rd party would send along a GET value that will tell the server to go into frame mode. But this will require control over the other site.

Comment: @Battle_707  I agree it's better to handle it server side if possible but there is no way to tell a request for an iframe from any other request at the server unless, as you say, there is some other GET param.

Comment: @Endophage you are right the code could be simplified, I actually copied that from a Google search result.

Comment: The ideal solution would be a passed variable of some kind, but staying within the parameters of the question this is the best solution.

Comment: @Robin Back when I was in university we would lose 10% from whatever the work was, coursework, exam etc... for each time we did it that way.  We all learned pretty quickly but I see it all over the place in code I have to work with.

Comment: @Robin +1 by the way.  This is a reliable solution assuming it's not one of the ~5% of users that have js disabled.  You have to decide where you're going to take your losses in web development and 5% isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make another layout for the iframe pages, something like `app/views/layouts/iframe.html.erb`, that doesn't have your usual headers and footers, may have different CSS, etc.

Then you just need to make your controller actions use that layout when rendering, as appropriate. You can do that when if you call render explicitly, like this:

```
render "show", :layout => "iframe"
```

But it's probably simpler to set it at the controller level:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    layout "iframe", :only => "show"
end
```

You could also put your logic for choosing the correct layout (whatever it is -- I'm assuming that isn't really the thrust of the question) into a method:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    layout :current_layout

private
    def current_layout
        # Return the correct layout for the current request.
        params[:iframe] ? "iframe" : "application"
    end
end
```