# best way to determine whether a webpage is viewed in an iframe

Tags: php, iframe, browser-detection

Is there a way to determine whether the user is using a web page in side and iframe or is it normal browsing using PHP?

Comment: or isnt there a way to do this?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html

Comment: it is a javascript, I want to know whether I can do it in PHP

Comment: If you'd've actually read the article you'd see that it's very hard to impossible *in general*, even using Javascript. It's most certainly *impossible* using PHP, since PHP has absolutely no idea what's going on on the client.

Comment: my requirement is this; I have a site which has to view in two different ways when a user is viewing it in an iframe and viewing it normally. 

I know that I can pass a variable to do this, but I can only do it on the landing page unless i change every other link to have that url variable. 

Or else I can keep a session variable too, but if the user suddenly views the page outside of and iframe need to switch it to work for the normal browsing. 

what is the best way to do this?

thank you

Comment: so you're expecting your users to get the iframe source and decide to view it in a new window instead? in what case is that going to happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if site is inside iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe)

Comment: i found this one is more relavant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394051/best-way-to-customize-my-site-when-viewed-through-iframes

Answer (score 2):

Using the javascript code that @deceze mentioned above (I pasted it in below),

```
if (parent.frames.length > 0) { ... }
```

If the above code noticed the page was displayed within iframe, then call 'IAmInIFRAME.php'(just example) via ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some GET parameters to the request while using IFRAME.

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/iframe?iframe=1">
```

But while non-iframe request there wouldn't be this GET parameter.

You can check is this GET parameter presents and define it in the session.

So there would be different sessions for iframe and usual window.

Comment: this is helpful, but i need to make the navigations to work too, so basically I need to track the user is coming from a page here the URL had a get variable called iframe

Comment: your navigation will work. In the Session there will be a variable which determines is user came from iframe or form usual window

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to see if the parent's location and the current window's location is the same.  If it is the same, then the page was loaded normally, if it is different then the page was loaded in an iframe.

```
var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
```

This came from this website. http://www.24hourapps.com/2009/01/check-if-page-is-loaded-in-iframe-using.html, and it came from the SO question here [Check if site is inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe).

NOTE: In one test, I got a cross browser origin error but that would also only come if the two locations were different.