# How can I find the site from which an Iframe's html is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm doing development and the site is using iframes.  Sometimes, I've configured my localhost development environment to point to REST services on localhost, dev, test or prod.
Sometimes I point my localhost UI to also point to localhost, dev, test or prod.

A couple of times (at least), I've launched the app I'm developing in an iframe, but the iframe was loaded from the *wrong* site (e.g., dev instead of localhost).

**(Q) How can I (through javascript ideally) see if the iframe was loaded from localhost, dev, test or prod?**

To do this today I **open the Chrome/Firefox devtools**, go to the ***Network tab*** and **reload the app** and look at the URL that was used to launch the iframe, since I know what to look for this is easy, but requires me to reload the app.

**(Q) Is there a way to open the console (after the page has been loaded) and look to see where the IFrame came from?**

#### What I've Tried

I did a search and [this SO question, best way to determine if webpage is viewed in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266107/best-way-to-determine-whether-a-webpage-is-viewed-in-an-iframe) was helpful.  I could use `window.parent.frames.length` to see that an iframe was open, but when I tried to use `window.parent.frames[0].location`, the `location` is an empty object.

[This page](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-the-current-url-with-javascript.php) says `window.location.href` should include the URL of the window, and indeed it does work for normal web pages.

I have not dealt a lot with iframes, so I don't know what is normal behavior for an iframe.

In my case, our app has a button on the parent page that launches the iframe application.

**Doh... I feel a little stupid because I found the answer and it's quite obvious.**
But I'll leave the question, since I spent a little while creating it, and it might help someone else.